# Css Color menu Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I have an issue to do background on menu for each category through css example in the picture below. It is about Wordpress.

**Background 1 Category:**

[image]

**Background 2 Category:**

[image]

If I have your name on the menu Sport as would make the sport background with colors that I love through CSS in Wordpress.

Comment: what is you actual HTML/CSS? and question isnt elaborated

Comment: @Chandrakant Wordpress Php,Html.I want to make the menu background color as in the picture above. Any category. News,Sport,Funny, different colors to be background

Comment: but what is HTML you have written? or is it template?

Comment: @PajtimHadja Try my source xD

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Thanks Dear its Working. Can you help me also in this part of coding in the post to be these same color then the category and the post to be the same color! Is this class for the post (post-current-parent) also at the same time to be (current-menu-parent).
var check_exist = test.classList.contains("current-menu-item","current-post-item"); not work.

Comment: If menu is a post. You still use `current-menu-item` not `current-post-item`

Comment: If it works with the category but when you get the items for color reading above the menu is not displayed I want the articles to appear the same color for each category think you understand me !?

Comment: You can decide at the same time and this "current-post-item" because it shows not only color the items into categories.

Comment: Really hard to understand your wishes. Please explain more or capture picture about that. For next comment please tag me so I can know you give one respone

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Dear tan in color category I sit and when I click any color that post The category is removed so if I have news that the red color appears in the category, but if I click the menu item is not displayed above the color menu...

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Its Okey Category:
https://i.imgsafe.org/f6a8cc836e.png

On post not displayed color.
https://i.imgsafe.org/f6ab2ba6b0.png

Comment: var check_menu_exist = test.classList.contains('current-menu-item');
var check_post_exist = test.classList.contains('current-post-parent');
if(check_menu_exist || check_post_exist){//do_change_color}

Comment: Thanks dear now its Work! Thanks for understand!
Sincerely,
Pajtim

Comment: Can you vote up for my answer. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Sorry maybe I touch something wrong'm new here Thank you to feel bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `javascript` code in this case
Insert to your `header.php` or anything similar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var test = document.getElementById("menu-item-26");
        var check_exist = test.classList.contains("current-menu-item");
        if(check_exist){
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("header");
                x[0].style.backgroundColor="#333";
        }
    });
</script>
```

1. Change `menu-item-26` to `id_of_your_menu`
2. Keep `current-menu-item` Because when menu selected this class will be added in your menu
3. Change `header` class to your class you want to change background.
4. Set your color.

That's all.

My result

[image]

---

**Original**

[image]